# Border on hover and cropping the image inside element

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to add an inner border to parent on hover, make the image stay put and get cropped to the same pixels as the border of the parent.

Any ideas?

HTML

```
<ul class="videoList">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flir.com/uploadedImages/Thermography_USA/Industries/ATS/Images/160x120-Uncooled-bolometer-E40-motorcycle.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.flir.com/uploadedImages/Thermography_USA/Industries/ATS/Images/160x120-Uncooled-bolometer-E40-motorcycle.jpg" /></a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.videoList {padding:0;}
.videoList li {box-sizing:border-box;float:left;padding:0;display:block;}
.videoList li img {display: block;}
.videoList li:hover {border:solid 5px #eb6c34;}
```

fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lon213n/1/

P.S. IE9+ must be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element :

```
.videoList li:hover:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:solid 5px #eb6c34;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lon213n/3/)**

Note that if your image is a link, you need to set the pseudo element on the `<a>` element to enable cliking :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lon213n/6/)**

Comment: @BillK pseudo generated content is supported by IE8+ see here : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Comment: thanks a lot for your time, and thanks for the update you make with the anchors!